# AWS Recommended Provisioned IOPS SSD (IO1) size for EBS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, provisioned-iops

I understand that `IOPS` improves performance and therefore, I want to use it for my `SQL Server Standard 2014 EC2` instance.

I have a Volume of 400GB and now wondering how much `IOPS` should I use. Previous month I used about 15,000 `IOPS` and got a huge bill for that (over 2000$), so that I want to reduce it to a normal cost and still have a good performance benefit from it.

Could you please advice/recommend me how many `IOPS` should I have for my `EBS`? Or some article that can explain it?

Comment: hi, I am guessing that you are using PIOPS ( Provisioned IOPS ) volumes on a EC2 that has SQL Server software installed by you?  Why aren't you using RDS?  Noone can advise you on "how many IOPS" as you haven't said what your actual load is.  Have you tried looking at the graphs in cloudwatch?

Comment: @Vorsprung Yes, you are right PIOPs...
I have some limits in the RDS so that I can't use it right now. I haven't looked the graphs in cloudwatch and I will probably not understand them. Where can I learn about it?

Comment: You have to measure **your** metrics. I can tell you that my SQL Server (on premise) has at some workload about 500-1200 IOPS average and ~ 39,000 IOPS maximum, but this informations are useless for you.